# Modifying your profile's web presence to a Bitbucket link instead of a GitHub link

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Currently you are able to show off your GitHub profile on your profile page.

[image: GitHub profile page link]

I however am not a huge fan of [GitHub](http://github.com) and use [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org).

Could we perhaps add support for other source control hosting providers like [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) and [Visual Studio Online](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/what-is-visual-studio-online-vs.aspx)?

Comment: Could have sworn there was an answer to this already, but all i can find are unanswered feature requests. Here's one: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253695/bitbucket-link-on-my-profile

Comment: Kind-of cross-site dupe, the plan is to let you put any links you want on your profile: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253551/261748

Comment: Such service specific data is prone to break with time: tomorrow there will be a new one that people will want, and the list will just grow larger. New ones could be added, but maybe the most elegant option is to just store a big amorphous list of links in user defined order?

Comment: Or just add a link to your profile... SO could retain support for GitHub, add some more web services, and then the rest can just be links (because they're less used).

Comment: Given what's happened recently, this feature requests seems *so* much more relevant nowadays...

Comment: @Stijn:  In all honesty I was going to post my own feature request since it really stopped making sense to couple that feature to a single platform.  I'm just glad someone else had the same idea three years prior.

Comment: @Makoto yeah, I do agree with that. Bitbucket isn't exactly a small player so it makes sense to add it (and some others).

Comment: @Makoto Has Microsoft done anything bad yet, or are you just preparing for them to do bad in the future?

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom:  It's less about Microsoft and more about "Oh, there actually *are* other hosted Git providers.  It'd be nice to be able to link those in my Stack Overflow profile."  Also, a coupling this tight should be frowned upon anyway since (as the OP here illustrates) not everyone likes GitHub.

Comment: My git profile is hosted on Gitlab.com not Github... Yet, my profile on SO makes it seem like I don't use git ! 250K++ repos were moved out of Github in the last couple days, most went to GitLab.com, a lot went self hosted.

Comment: My Idea is to just add a whitelist... You'll make 99% of people happy with that. If your git is hosted on your own site, allowing a path like "mysite.app/git" for your site to work would make the other 1% happy.

Comment: I moved my main Git presence to notabug and I am still expected or favored to have a Github link, which doesn't make much sense. Has this issue seen any advancement?

Comment: Nowadays, Gitlab is very popular, what about adding a link now?