# Why is there no GitLab option in the profile settings?

Tags: discussion, profile-page, accounts

There is a field for "GitHub link or username", but there is no option if we host our repositories on other sites such as GitLab and wish to display our GitLab username instead.

Comment: Probably because GitLab is not nearly as popular or impactful as GitHub?

Comment: There's no BitBucket, SourceForge, ... - for better or worse, GitHub has a unique position in the online hosting space. Just add any other links you want to share to your description.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I guess the question is why does GitHub have such a "unique position in the online hosting space"? Or more to the point, why does SO show them such deference? I'm sure that whatever goes into that field could just as easily have been the online hosting site of the user's choice. How does it serve the community to give preference to GitHub?

Comment: @NicolBolas that's absolutely *not* the question, or at least not one that's on topic for SOMeta! It seems likely that GitHub is special-cased *because* it's so prevalent, but beyond that I can't answer. See also https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253695/248731, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/309552/3001761

Comment: This may have to be revisited with the recent news. Gitlab's popularity may increase by a lot.

Comment: Nowadays, Gitlab is very popular, what about adding a link now?